# How do I stop this loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops

How do I stop this infinite loop if I press "no" on the confirm dialog?

```
        int loop=0;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Select your food. 1");
            int f=scan.nextInt();
            if(f==1)
            {
                System.out.println("\nHow many tenderloin do you like? ");
                ps=scan.nextInt();
                pst=ps*55;
            }
            System.out.println("Select your drinks. 1");
            int d=scan.nextInt();
            if(d==1)
            {
                System.out.println("\nHow many filtered water do you want? ");
                fw=scan.nextInt();
                fwt=fw*16;
            }
            int buttonClicked=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do You Want To Order Again?","Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }
        while(JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION!=done);
        loop++;
            System.out.println("TOTAL: ");
    }
}
```

I can't get the logic.

Comment: `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION != buttonClicked`?

Comment: This seems an odd mixture of command line input and GUI input.  I'd recommend making it one or the other.

Comment: use break; statement to terminate the loop.

Comment: I agree with MadP here, and why do you use `loop++` outside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Move your definition of `buttonClicked` to outside the loop. And test against the value [`JOptionPane.YES_OPTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#YES_OPTION). Something like,

```
int buttonClicked;
do
{
  // ...
  buttonClicked = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
          "Do You Want To Order Again?","Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
} while(buttonClicked == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line `while(JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION!=done);` to `while(JOptionPane.NO_OPTION!=buttonClicked);`